# Using IDW tool in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, inverse-distance-weighted, precipitation

In ArcGIS Desktop 10.7 we have [IDW tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/idw.htm), but when you want to work with it you should need two layers such as : Some points and a closed polyline (Boundary) as following:

[image]

then using IDW:

[image]

but I have a problem. my data is not point is a polyline (Actually is a line joining points of equal rainfall on a map in a given period) as following:

[image]

How should I use IDW tool?

This is because I don't have the lines in the first box of IDW tool:

[image]

Comment: You have rainfall contours. IDW does not work with contour data.  You could use the topo to raster tool, which uses a thin-plate spline interpolator, but that tool is specifically designed for elevation data and I have no idea how appropriate it would be for rainfall data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution!
I think I should convert the feature to points by using "Feature Vertices to Points" Tool in

Data Management Tool > Feature.

why? bcoz in the real world we have discrete data not continues so the polylines are actually some simple lines between some points.

**the definition of "isohyetal":**
is a line joining points of equal rainfall on a map in a given period.

the points are actually are the vertices of the polylines.

[image]

as you see the polylines have been converted to some points.
[image]

now we should use IDW tool:

[image]

to choose "Z value field" in above you should find the rainfall column in the attribute table of the shapefile:
[image]

the next step on the IDW window you should click on the Environment Button and then click on the "Raster Analysis" to choose your closed Boundary:

[image]

[image]

now you see the result:

[image]

good luck